# How to use wildcards in uriPattern for jetpack compose navigation deep links?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, deep-linking, jetpack-compose-navigation

I am trying to implement deep links in my android app using Compose Navigation. I am following the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation#deeplinks) but got stuck at one problem. I want my composable to intercept all urls with the prefix `https://www.example.com` i.e. I want that composable to load for `https://www.example.com/abc`, `https://www.example.com/a/b/c`, etc.

What should I pass in `uriPattern`?

When I use just `https://www.example.com`, the composable only opens for `https://www.example.com` and not for `https://www.example.com/abc` or any other link. I tried using some wildcard like `https://www.example.com/**` but that doesn't work.

Comment: What did you use in your manifest for `android:pathPattern` for the associated `<intent-filter>`?

Comment: scheme="https" and host="www.example.com". The app opens when any of the above links are clicked. The issue is that it opens at home screen and not the screen (composable) where i am putting the deep link uri pattern

Comment: The [guide to creating a deep link](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/design/deep-link#implicit) says that `.*` is the syntax for wildcards. Is there a reason you didn't try that?

Comment: That worked. Thankss! I hadn't checked that guide.